# How to I access this particular class?

Tags: java-7, java, sun

The class in question is [`sun.security.tools.KeyTool`](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/sun/security/tools/KeyTool.html) and I'm using OpenJDK 7. I keep getting "cannot find symbol" though, and I'm no Java expert so I can't figure out through documentation why that could be or if it's gone. Any ideas?

Exact error message:

```
Main.java:1: error: cannot find symbol
import sun.security.tools.KeyTool;
                         ^
  symbol:   class KeyTool
  location: package sun.security.tools
```

Code:

```
import sun.security.tools.KeyTool;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your code? What have you tried? What's the exact error message, and when do you get it?

Comment: @AntonH I get it on compilation. javac version 1.7.0_131. My code is `import sun.security.tools.KeyTool;` and an empty class.

Comment: @AntonH I added more detail to the question if it wasn't clear.

Comment: @c0der Add an external jar for `sun.*`? Are you sure? To clarify, `import sun.security.tools.*;` works just fine — it's only `KeyTool` that seems to be missing.

Comment: Use `import sun.security.tools.keytool.*;`

Comment: @c0der Thanks for the suggestion, but in that case I get `error: package sun.security.tools.keytool does not exist` (even with different capitalization).

Comment: I know you said your `import sun.security.tools.*` works but since I'm not really sure what else your importing you can give this a quick look http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/p11guide.html.  Make sure your 2 security libraries live in `$JAVA_HOME/lib/security`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `javac -XDignore.symbol.file ...`.

By default `javac` restricts the classes it exposes to users. This generally helps users avoid accidentally depending on (unsupported) classes that are not public Java API but happen to be available in the current JRE/JDK. The list of "safe" classes is described in `ct.sym` file. The `ignorel.symbol.file` system property tells javac to ignore that file and make use of all classes available in the JDK/JRE.

And make sure you add `tools.jar`, where this class is defined to the classpath for javac.

Comment: Do you know why it's necessary to add tools.jar? When I use Java 8, everything works fine without the extra classpath, although I do have to use `-XDignore.symbol.file`. Do you know why that flag is needed too?

Comment: I added an explanation of `-XDignore.symbol.file.` As for Oracle Java 8 vs OpenJDK 7, I am not sure. Compare OpenJDK 8 to see what it does. Set the `_JAVA_LAUNCHER_DEBUG` environment variable to see what classes are added to the classpath by the launcher.

Comment: A reminder note for future readers:  in Java 8, the keytool (and jarsigner) code moved into their own packages, so the `sun.security.tools.KeyTool` class became `sun.security.tools.keytool.Main`.  The public access function is still `main()`.

Answer (score 0):

In Java 8+ the class is moved to `sun.security.tools.keytool.Main` and you access it via `javac --add-exports=java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool=ALL-UNNAMED`